# 'Trying to get property of non-object' error when attempting ->num_rows on inner join statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to print out both Product_Name from the product table and Order_Date from the order table but keep getting the error on line 35 the "num_rows line".

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username='root';
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";
?>
<html><<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cart</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabMenu.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>

<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username, Null, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}  

session_start();

$results="Select orderline.Order_Date,p.Product_Name"
       . "from orderline"
       . "inner join product p"
       . "on orderline.Product_ID=p.Product_ID";   

$num=$mysqli->query($results);



if ($results->num_rows)
   {
    while ($row=$results->fetch_object())
            {
        echo "{$row->Order_Date} {$row->Product_ID} <br>";
            }
   }
   else
   {
   echo "No Results";}
```

Thanks in advance any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$results` is a `string`, strings are not objects in PHP (at least not normally).

You need to look at the `num_rows` property of the [results object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php):

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query($results);
$numRows = $resultSet->num_rows;

if ($numRows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_object()) {
        echo "{$row->Order_Date} {$row->Product_ID} <br>";
    }
}
```

[**Here is some documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)